# migrate signalr to azure signalr in net standard

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

I have an application in .NET 4.5.2 that uses SignalR to communicate between the frontend and backend. We are planning to migrate to Azure SignalR, but unfortunately, it is not compatible with our version of .NET. As a result, we are considering creating a .NET Core application that solely handles Azure SignalR hubs (acting as a proxy) to which the backend and frontend will connect. Is this feasible? Are there any other solutions we could consider?

Comment: could you share the code or error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Although Azure SignalR Service is not compatible with .NET 4.x versions of SignalR you can use your version within your app service and not use Azure SignalR Service. Link to [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67974151/do-i-have-to-use-azure-signalr-for-a-signalr-service-deployed-to-azure#:%7E:text=SignalR%20started%20way%20back%20in,Azure%20SignalR%20Service%20just%20fine.) regarding.

As far as having a CORE version acting as a proxy, that is unlikely to work out as you still have the issue of .NET 4.x version incompatibility with .NET CORE versions.

Comment: Why wouldn't the solution of a .NET Core app acting as a proxy work? Once deployed, I can simply use jQuery libraries on both the backend and frontend, which would then both become client. Thanks!

Comment: If your front end using jQuery is .NET 4.x framework, it cannot connect to a SignalR .NET CORE because they are incompatible. "ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-8.0